Why is there oily residue on my plumbing torch?
I have a pro grade benzomatic plumbing torch without a hose. It's the type that screws directly onto to small gas bottle.
I recently bought a hose adapter which allows me to connect it to a larger 20lb propane tank.
As I use it I find oily residue building up and its igniter is less effective ( presumably because it is fouled by this residue). The oily residue does not smell, so I don't think it's mercaptan.
I don't think it's an issue with the propane since the larger and smaller tanks originate in the same supplier so I think it must be the hose.
I've read some discussions online about propane leeching plasticizers and oils out of rubber hoses but I'm unsure if that's it.
What could cause this? If it is a problem with the hose, is there a different (better) type of hose to use for this application?

A guess, since the residue is apparently forming in the burn chamber where the ignitor is: the larger tank has more pressure, and the propane may not be burning fully in the small-capacity burn chamber designed for smaller tanks and lower pressure. Maybe a regulator is needed?

What could cause this? ... you answered that question in the sentence directly before the question ... is there a different (better) type of hose ... that cannot be answered without knowing what hose you are using

Propane and all LP gas is frequently contaminated with oily residue. Quoting from an article in The Analytical Scientist:

LPG is prone to oily residues that accumulate to form troublesome
deposits that corrode or plug fuel filters, pressure regulators, fuel
mixers or control solenoids. It can become contaminated by oily
residue in just about any part of the production and transportation
lifecycle. Transport contamination alone can occur in shared
pipelines, valves and trucks used for the distribution of other
products.

The article goes on to say that the residue consists of C10 through C40 compounds, i.e., compounds that contain 10-40 carbon atoms instead of the 3 carbons of propane.
I've seen this residue myself in 20 lb propane tanks that I've repurposed for other uses. The fact that you're not seeing oily residue from smaller tanks may mean that these tanks are getting better filtration when they are filled.
I don't think the hose has anything to do with it.
If oily residue were causing problems for my torch, I'd give it a quick shot of carb cleaner when the residue became noticeable.

Incidentally, propane gas filters are available with proper LPG fittings. Some can be installed between the tank valve and regulator or tank valve and hose fitting.
